# PHP Saving and Reusing timestamps

Tags: php, timestamp

I want to use timestamps.

I know that this outputs a timestamps:

```
$date = date_create();
echo date_format($date, 'U');
```

But I want to know how to make use of that time stamp.
--> save it to a database, the later convert it to required timezone and then output it in the format that I choose.

I just don't know how to do that.

How can I use a time stamp?

Comment: What do you want to use the timestamps for?

Comment: you don't how to store data in mysql database?

Comment: You can generate the timestamp when you insert into database.

Comment: I want to use a time stamp to record the time when posts were submitted, and want to then convert that time stamp to the users timezone and display it. BTW I know how to save to a database and retrieve. Just not how to handle it.

Comment: you can use the php date function to formate it as you please

Comment: but how exactly?  I tried this: date_timestamp_set($date, 1171502725);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); and it did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your intent is just to store and then show your timestamps you can let mysql do the job.

Your table DDL might look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `post` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Important part `DEFAULT`[`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp)
That way current timestamp will be assigned to post_date column on `INSERT`

```sql
INSERT INTO `posts` (`post`) VALUES ('post1');
```

Then you can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to fetch formatted timestamp data from mysql

```sql
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') post_date, post 
FROM `posts`
```

Output

```
+----+---------------------+-------+
| id | post_date           | post  |
+----+---------------------+-------+
|  1 | 02/20/2013 23:45:43 | post1 |
|  2 | 02/20/2013 23:45:43 | post2 |
+----+---------------------+-------+
```

But you if you want to format it in php you can use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) in your query first

```sql
SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_date) post_date, post FROM `posts`
```

and then format it with `date()` like this, assuming that you fetched a row to `$row` by your favorite extension (PDO or mysqli)

```php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$row['post_date']);
```

output

```
02/20/2013 23:45:43
```